# How to convert .wav file into byte array?

Tags: java, file

I have a `.wav` file in my disk drive. I need to convert that `.wav` file to `byte array` using java.

Can anyone help?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Study the [WAV file format](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/).

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Files.readAllBytes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes%28java.nio.file.Path%29) to achieve this.

> Read all the bytes from a file. The method ensures that the file is
>   closed when all bytes have been read or an I/O error, or other runtime
>   exception, is thrown.

Comment: +1 for pointing out one of the less known new features in Java 7. That said, I am not sure if the OP actually wants the whole file as a byte array, or just the audio...

Comment: Be careful though, this will read the 44 header bytes too; you'll need to skip them. This method worked for me too.

Answer (score 3):

For JRE < 1.7, regardless of extension

```
File file = new File(filePath);
InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)file.length()];
fis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
fis.close();
```

Comment: How does this treat the file header?